# JSON decoding to dictionary

Tags: ios, swift

I need to decode a JSON to a dictionary. The json has String key and the values are strings or numbers.

```
   let decoder = JSONDecoder()
   let dict = try decoder.decode([String: Any].self, from: data)
```

This throws an exception about Any not being decodable. If I use [String : String] it trows an exception about finding a number when a string is expected.

How to do this right?

Comment: Why don't you decode as a model not a dictionary?

Comment: Because I want this to be in a general function .. nothing specific.

Comment: then use the old JSONSerialization way I think is better for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the any to model and decode it

```
struct Swifter: Decodable {
    let fullName: String
    let id: Int
    let twitter: URL
}

let json = """
    {
        "fullName": "Federico Zanetello",
        "id": 123456,
        "twitter": "http://twitter.com/zntfdr"
}
""".data(using: .utf8)! // our data in native (JSON) format
let myStruct = try JSONDecoder().decode(Swifter.self, from: json) // Decoding our data
print(myStruct) // decoded!!!!!
```

Or you can try this if you have son data

```
let responseDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
```

Comment: I don't want to use models ... This should work for any json that is received ...

Comment: you can decode only array , Swifter.self for single object or [Swifte].self for array , see edit...